# Как заменить одно значения двух массивов, чтобы после замены у них было одинаковая сумма. (java)

Tags: java

Помогите написать код на Java!!!

Имеется массив `array1={1,2,5}`и `array2={2,4}`. Нужно заменить одно число из каждого массива так, чтобы сумма чисел в каждом массиве была равной. Для этого надо сначала определить какие это будут числа и затем вывести их.

```
Например,

array1={1,2,5} и array2={2,4}

Вывод = {5,4}
```

Т.е. после замены массивы будут выглядеть так: array1={1,2,4} и array2={2,5}

Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: Уважаемый пользователь, приложите пожалуйста, свои наработки по данному вопросу!. И прочитайте правила по оформлениям вопросов на SO!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код:

```
public static void doIt(int[] a, int[] b) {
 int[] tmp_a = a.clone(), tmp_b = b.clone();

 for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  for (int j = b.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
   swap(tmp_a, tmp_b, i, j);

   int sum_a = sum(tmp_a);
   int sum_b = sum(tmp_b);

   if (sum_a == sum_b) {
    System.out.println("In Array A: " + Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println("In Array B: " + Arrays.toString(b));
    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("Swap: {" + a[i] + ", " + b[j] + "}");
    System.out.println("Sum Array A: " + sum_a + ", Sum Array B: " + sum_b);
    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("Out Array A: " + Arrays.toString(tmp_a));
    System.out.println("Out Array B: " + Arrays.toString(tmp_b));
    return;
   }
  }
 }

 System.out.println("Error!");
}

public static int sum(int[] arr) {
 return Arrays.stream(arr).sum();
}

public static void swap(int[] arr0, int[] arr1, int a, int b) {
 arr0[a] = arr0[a] + arr1[b];
 arr1[b] = arr0[a] - arr1[b];
 arr0[a] = arr0[a] - arr1[b];
}
```

Вывод:

```
In Array A: [1, 2, 5]
In Array B: [2, 4]
------------------
Swap: {5, 4}
Sum Array A: 7, Sum Array B: 7
------------------
Out Array A: [1, 2, 4]
Out Array B: [2, 5]
```